# Don't resize div to a contained image

Tags: html, css

I want to createa a div, who has some links, and a logo image. The thing is that I don't want that the div to resize to the image size. I want that the image ovelap the div. I want something like the image. But when I add the image inside the div, the div size is increased to contain the image.

[image]

Comment: Without your code and attempts and telling us where / why / what you are stuck with it is impossible to help you.

Comment: @PeeHaa Impossible. Exactly why there are 3 answers which are all helpful. I think the picture is very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are saying is that you want to remove the image from normal flow. There are several ways to do that:

### Float

```
img {
    float: left;
    margin: <position it with this>;
}
```

Floating is handy because it will remove the element from normal flow, while still giving you the option of clearing the float. It will also push the `float: right` navigation away when near. The only downside is that it's not as powerful as absolute.

### Absolute

```
#nav {
    position: relative; /* child positioned in relation to the first element with non-static position */
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: <position it with this>;
    top: <position it with this>;
}
```

Absolute completely removes the element from flow, so it won't interfere with anything, including the right navigation (this could be a downside). You can position it accurately with `left` and `top`.

### Negative Margin

```
img {
    margin-bottom: <some negative number>;
}
```

This will pull the bottom of the container up, making it look like it's out of normal flow, without the consequences of that. I personally prefer this solution. It will work as long as you can calculate the correct margin-bottom for it to look right.

### Plain, fixed height

```
#nav {
    height: <some height>;
}
```

The simplest solution: just give your navigation a set height.

Comment: I'm doing the page to be responsive, which of the answers is the best one for that? Does absolute position interfere with resposive design?

Comment: It depends. Is the image responsive, or just the nav? If you can avoid the collisions with absolute (using media queries), then you should probably do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `absolute` positioning:

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="image">Image Div</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
}


.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

You can try it [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IyEgo/).